# Highcharts - change pie slice color on existing chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart that already exists. I need to change the color of a specific slice. I have tried ...

```
chart.series[0].data[4].graphic.attr({ fill: '#FF0000' });
```

But this only changes the color temporarily until the item is hovered over. I have also tried the normal changing of the options method.

How do I change it for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) method, like this:

```
chart.series[0].data[4].update({ color: '#FF0000' });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpy23g6f/).